# Im creating a rest api using node.js and in .get method i want to get back a json array

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im creating a rest api using Node.js and in the `.get` method I want to get back a JSON array which contains in the header the title of the entity and down the rest of data.

This is my code:

```js
app.get('/evenement/show', (req, res) => {

    con.query('SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER BY date_debut_evenement desc',((err, results, fields) => {
        if(!err){
            res.send(results);
        }
        else {
            console.log(err)

        }
    }))

});
```

```js
[
    {
        "id_evenement": 1,
        "nom_evenement": "testtttttt",
        "type_evenement": "test",
        "date_debut_evenement": "2019-11-19T17:58:23.000Z",
        "date_fin_evenement": "2019-11-19T17:58:23.000Z",
        "distance_evenement": "50",
        "photo_evenement": "test",
        "lieux_evenement": "test"
    },
    {
        "id_evenement": 2,
        "nom_evenement": "user",
        "type_evenement": "user",
        "date_debut_evenement": "2019-11-12T23:00:00.000Z",
        "date_fin_evenement": "2019-11-18T23:00:00.000Z",
        "distance_evenement": "50",
        "photo_evenement": "user",
        "lieux_evenement": "user"
    }
]
```

That's how im getting the data right now 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISPLk.png)
I want it just like that 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBAvI.png)

Comment: Sooooo what's your question? The code there looks fine. You haven't told us anything about what the problem is.

Comment: How is the data getting returned right now as-is? What is the structure of that `results` object?

Comment: check it i have added it

Comment: I still don't see what your issue is. That is indeed a regular JSON array of objects. The code you have should work. Is the client not parsing it to an array or something? If so try using `res.status(200).json(results)`. You still have not asked a question, you asked "how do I do this thing?" while posting the code you have that looks perfectly valid. What is the issue you have with it right now as it stands?

Comment: the sql query is already written, and it works fine, i just want to change the display of data, just reading what im getting in return on the screenshots will give you a global vision on the table, no need to all this cruelty, instead of that thank you for trying to help me

Comment: Sorry, it just confused me that your image of what you wanted it to look like contained totally different properties than what you had. I thought you meant you wanted it to look EXACTLY like that. Which is why I assumed you might be looking for a different query.

Comment: it's okay my friend and thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
app.get('/evenement/show', (req, res) => {

    con.query('SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER BY date_debut_evenement desc',((err, results, fields) => {
        if(!err){           
            res.send({ evenements:results });
        }
        else {
            console.log(err)

        }
    }))

});
```

Comment: check the link that I have added, that's how i want to display my data, any help please?